# Avoiding Divide By 0 Error With Multiple Case Statements

Tags: sql-server, case, divide-by-zero

The following is part of a `SELECT` clause that is giving me divide by 0 error:

```
(SUM([Hours])/(SUM(CASE WHEN J.Description <> 'I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
```

The following is how I am rectifying the denominator for the divide by 0 error:

```
CASE WHEN(SUM(CASE WHEN J.Description <> 'I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN J.Description <> 'I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))  AS 'MTBUR'
```

This is leaving me syntactical errors.  What am I doing wrong?

So basically if the SUM = 0 then I want the denominator to be 1 ELSE

```
SUM(CASE WHEN J.Description <> 'I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE WHEN(SUM(CASE WHEN J.Description <> 'I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE SUM (CASE WHEN J.Description <> 'I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))` **END**  `AS 'MTBUR'`

Needed another `END` to end nested case

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Let the else portion of your case expression be NULL so the sum will be NULL if there are no rows where Description = 'I'

```
SUM([Hours]) /  ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN J.Description <> 'I' THEN 1 END), 1)
```